# Compile Error type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting type mismatch when running this code even though I didn't get an error when I wrote it below:

```
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Exportbook.xlsx").UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksUserSetting
```

or even

```
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Exportbook.xlsx").UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
```

---

```
Sub Comments()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Exportbook.xlsx"),UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksUserSetting
    Set y = ThisWorkbook x.Sheets("Tablets").Range("E10:AQ2000").Copy

    y.Sheets("Tablets").Range("E10:AQ2000").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments
    x.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

It ran fine until I added the updatelink part

Comment: Need to change your syntax: `Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Exportbook.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksUserSetting)`

Comment: I've tried that. I get compile error: expected end of statement even before I run it

Comment: The "expected end of statement" error has nothing to do with that specific line.  It means you are missing an `End With` or `Next` or `Loop`, or `End If` or similar somewhere in your code.  I'd have to see your code to give a better answer

Comment: Sub Comments()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Exportbook.xlsx"),UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksUserSetting
Set y = ThisWorkbook

x.Sheets("Tablets").Range("E10:AQ2000").Copy

y.Sheets("Tablets").Range("E10:AQ2000").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments

x.Close SaveChanges:=False  End Sub    It ran fine until I added the updatelink part

Comment: Do you see how you have the wrong placement for the ending parenthesis?  From your shown code: `Workbooks.Open("C:\Exportbook.xlsx"),UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksUserSetting`

Comment: Needs to be as I showed above: `Workbooks.Open("C:\Exportbook.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksUserSetting)`

Comment: Missed that.  Sorry.  Thanks.  Need to pay better attention. I just saw the :=.  thanks again.  It did work.